# Image capture and oval crop/trim with HTML5 getUserMedia()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, face-detection

I need to capture a users face via HTML5 with getUserMedia();  take a snapshot then save to to a cropped/trimmed png.

I can achieve the first part of actually capturing the image, it's the next step of how to crop and trim to an oval shape I'm stuck on.

```
// Put event listeners into place
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
// Grab elements, create settings, etc.
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    video = document.getElementById("video"),
    videoObj = { "video": true },
    errBack = function(error) {
        console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code); 
    };

// Put video listeners into place
if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
    navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
        video.src = stream;
        video.play();
    }, errBack);
} else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
        video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    }, errBack);
}
else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Firefox-prefixed
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play();
    }, errBack);
}
}, false);
// Trigger photo take
document.getElementById("snap").addEventListener("click", function() {
context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
});
```

Comment: Question edited to be more specific and to include code example